# Seeing what files are in a folder in my application

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm kind of new to ios developing and was wondering could I navigate through my own application with NSFileManager.

I have a folder inside my application and would like to see what files are in it and don't want to use hardcoded file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to get to know `NSFileManager`'s [`contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/contentsOfDirectoryAtPath%3aerror%3a) method (documentation linked for you).

To look within your own application bundle, pass a path of "[`[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]"`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/resourcePath).  This would give you a path to the "Resources" folder within your application bundle.  If you look at the linked documentation, you'll see NSBundle provides a few other potential ways to get paths to interesting locations within your application package.

Comment: I know how to use `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: error:` but i don't know how I would get the path of my project.  How would I do that?